# Expectation of a Product of Independent Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I was wondering if there was a formula for the expectation of a product of $n$ independent random variables. I have only seen one for two random variables.

I guess what I am asking is:

> Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be $n$ independent random variables. Is there a formula for $E\left(\prod\limits_{i=1}^n X_i\right)$?

I need this for a problem I am working on. It would be nice if it was equal to $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n E(X_i)$. While this is true when $n=2$, I'm not sure if this is true for general $n$.

If you are able to provide a formula for this I would appreciate a source or some sort of derivation.

Comment: What you want the answer to be is in fact what the answer is.

Answer (score 5):

If the values *are independent* then, it basically follows from the definition of expectation and the fact of independence of the series (that the joint probability function is the product of the marginal probability functions):

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E(\prod_i X_i) & = \iiint (\;\prod_i x_i f_i(x_i)\;)\; \mathrm d x_n\cdots\mathrm d x_1
\\ & = \int x_n f_n(x_n)\mathrm d x_n \cdot \iiint\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}x_if_i(x_i)\mathrm d x_{n-1}\cdots\mathrm d x_1
\\ & = \prod_i \int x_i f_i(x_i)\mathrm d x_i
\\ & = \prod_i \mathrm E(X_i)
\end{align}$$

Or you might prefer to use the Law of Iterative Expectation: $$\begin{align}
\mathsf E(\prod_{i=1}^n X_i) & = \mathsf E(\mathsf E(X_n\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} X_i\mid X_n)) \\ & = \mathsf E(X_n\mathsf E(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} X_i)) \\ & = \mathsf E(X_n)\mathsf E(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} X_i) \\ & = \prod_{i=1}^n \mathsf E(X_i)\end{align}$$

Comment: Do we need the integrability of $\prod_iX_i$?

Comment: Well, the expectation has to exist. @AddSup  So we need all of the $x_i f_i(x_i)$ function to each be integrable, wrt their arguments, $x_i$,  over their supports.  (Or summable if the support is discrete. )

Comment: Thank you. Assuming the integrability of each $X_i$ is natural, so it may be left not spelled out; but I was wondering if independence among them, via the above formula, guarantees the integrability of $\prod_iX_i$ (i.e., we don't get $E\prod_iX_i=\infty$).

Comment: If the expectations of the individuals all exist, and they are independent, then the expectation of their product exists. @AddSup

Comment: I see. It follows from Fubini. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, if $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are independent, the expected value of the product is the product of the expected values.